# Що таке "гиргоші"

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Нещодавно почув як двоє чоловіків розмовляли і один із них сказав, що його син "любить лазити на гиргоші". Однак мої спроби знайти це слово в СУМі-11 чи СУМі-20 не дали ніяких результатів.

Сумнівів немає, що це якийсь діалектизм, але цікаво було б дізнатися, що він означає. Зараз у мене є лише версія, що може це якась діалектне слово, що означає "гори".

Comment: Мені одному ґуґлопошук [першим же рядком](https://www.google.com/search?q=гиргоші) дає правильну відповідь — навіть незважаючи на одрук?

Comment: @bytebuster, який саме у Вас перший рядок? У мене zkan.com.ua — сайт, на який абсолютно не варто дивитися. Бо він просто рясніє «перлами» на зразок [«Як правильно писати: брелоки або брелоки?»](http://zkan.com.ua/chomy/jak-pravilno-pisati-breloki-abo-breloki.html) (невдалий автоматичний переклад з [«Как правильно писать: брелки или брелоки?»](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/118959-kak-pravilno-pisat-brelki-ili-breloki.html); загалом, наскільки я розумію, увесь zkan.com.ua — це муляж, створений автоматичним перекладом окр. сторінок з bolshoyvopros.ru, жодного справжнього контенту).

Comment: На гиргошах - на плечах кататися)

Comment: В нас, на Тернопільщині кажуть схоже "Ґарґоші"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

«Словник укр. мови» в 11 томах:

> [ГОРГО́ШІ](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghorghoshi), гош, мн., діал. Плечі. — Клунка свого не дам, бо я ще й вас могла б узяти на горгоші з вашою торбою разом (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 348).
>
> ---
>
> [КОРКО́ШІ](http://sum.in.ua/s/korkoshi), ів, мн., діал. Плечі. Андрусь.. приніс мене на коркошах (Іван Франко, IV, 1950, 187); Під гору взяв дід внука на коркоші (Марко Черемшина, Тв., 1960, 34).

«Словник укр. мови» в 20 томах:

> [КОРКО́ШІ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44198&page=1398), ів, мн., діал. Плечі. Андрусь .. приніс мене на коркошах
>   (І. Франко); Під гору взяв дід внука на коркоші
>   (Марко Черемшина).

[Допис Azzurro на форумі ABBYY Linvgo](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:forum.lingvolive.com/thread/l117377/) ([оригінал, що вже не доступний](http://forum.lingvolive.com/thread/l117377/); [кеш кешу](http://archive.fo/94kv4)) наводить багато інформації щодо вживання цього слова в *російській* мові; але оскільки інформація цікава, дуже ретельно дібрана й, імовірно, стосується української мови теж (слово має, імовірно, праслов'янське походження і вживається здебільшого на теренах України, хай навіть і при російськомовному спілкуванні), то я наведу її повністю (у власному перекладі на українську, російський оригінал можна переглянути за посиланнями вище, примітки у фігурних дужках мої):

> **Горгоші (гаргоші)** і **гиргоші**, зазвичай у висловах **на го(/и)ргоші**, **на го(/и)ргошах**.
>   **Наголос**: на 2-й склад.
>   **Значення**: верхня частина спини, плечі, рос. [закорки](//dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/806358) {тут посилання додане мною}.
>   **Регіон**: Одеса і  обл., Молдавія.
>   Примітка: спорадично тж. західна Україна.
>   **Статус**: регіонально розмовне, особ. дитяче.
>   **Походження слова**: імов., від {пра}слов'янської назви шиї (**корк*), із вторинним (можл., експресивним) переходом до дзвінких (пор. нижче *коркоші* й ін. форми з глухим консонантизмом).
>   Фіксація в {російських} словниках: не фіксується.
>   Пор. «Тлумачний словник української мови» *[горгóші](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96), -гóш*, діал. «плечі», *[коркóші](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%96), -iв*, зах. — тс {тут посилання оновлені мною, бо [подане в оригіналі](http://www.slovnyk.net) посилання на матеріали «Великого тлумачного словника сучасної української мови» вже не працює}.
>
> Приклади вживання:
>
> - ОДЕСА Й ОБЛ.
>
>   - *«Я маю троє маленьких дітей. Зараз, cлава Богу, двоє в санаторії, то мені доводиться лише одну тягати на „горгошах“. А взимку всіх трьох через калюжі тягала до школи, зі школи таким чином»* [(з інтерв'ю; портал ІА «Репортер», Одеса, 15.06.2004)](http://www.reporter.com.ua/news/6623/) {тут посилання оригінальне}.
>   - *«А ми сидимо в мами на горгошах і їмо кашу. По-іншому сьогодні не впхнеш»* (форум про дітей, автор з Одеси).
>   - *«…Обожнює дивитися тєлєк, кататися в мене на колінах, малювати, купатися, їздити на горгошах…»* (щоденник молодої мами, Одеса).
>   - *«Кататися на горгошах у темряві веселіше»* (молодіжний музичний форум, автор з Одеси; народився 1991 р.).
>   - *«Аяяй Президенте! Як не соромно? Буквально на горгошах у Тимошенко став президентом, і жодної подяки. А ким би взагалі був би Ющенко, якби не Тимошенко?»* (український політичний портал, коментар з Одеси).
>   - *«А представниця Африки не стала дожидати розбірок і шмигнула по плечах людей, що намагатися схопити її, на протилежний бік Дерибасівської. Дорогою не забувши вихопити в якогось малюка, що сидів на горгошах у татуся, чудовий банан»* (Олександр Медведєв, «У Грибоєдова», гумористичне оповідання, 2004; автор з Одеси).
>   - *«Це дядько Гена, з Одеси, саме той, що тебе впродовж всього Єгипту носив на „гаргошах“, плечах»* (коментар на сторінці юного актора).
>   - *«Все, що нижче, люди позривали, а цю [листівку] приклеїли високо. Буду з кимось повертатися ввечері — влізу на гаргоші, щоб здерти»* (громадський форум, автор з Одеси).
>   - *«…Від „на луськи“ [= на ручки] вона [бабуся] відмазалася, нічого, прийде дідусь з рейсу, затягає і на ручках, і на горгошках»* (форум про діточок, автор з Одеси).
>   - *«Хочеться іноді стати маленькою дівчинкою, щоб тато катав на гиргошах, мати носила на ручках та зав'язувала два хвостики й бантики…»* (щоденник, Одеса; автор народилася 1990 р.).
>   - *«Сідай коханому на гиргоші-плечі, ніжки будуть під його пахвами, і поганяй його бігцем»* (форум, автор з Одеси).
>   - *«Сті[ль]ки народу, але ми були й не так уже далеко від сцени, і тим паче я у Вови на плечах сиділа, ну на гиргошах!»* (щоденник, Одеса).
>   - *«Дотепно зроблена з гіпсу, видимо, постать чоловіка, що тримає на плечах (або, як казали в моєму дитинстві, „на гиргошах“) хлопчика, і вони заглядають з вулиці у вікно ресторану. Якось смішно. По-одеськи»* (форум, Одеса).
>   - *«Плечі — це не зовсім ги(о)(а)ргоші. На гиргоші означає ззаду застрибнути, руками триматися за плечі, тобто типу верхи»* (форум про дітей, Одеса).
>
>   Пор.:
>
>   - *«І друзі шкільні деякі „пропали“, і сусід сходами красень, що на „гиргошах“ мене носив (все казав, як підросту, одружиться зі мною), у 22 чи 24 роки в тюрягу загримів…»* (форум, автор родом з Одеси, нині — Італія).
>   - *«Так, у Бессарабії все дитинство катали виключно „на горгошах“»* (коментар у Живому журналі, автор родом з м. Білгород-Дністровський Одеської обл.).
>
>   Пор. тж.:
>
>   - *«А якщо треба буває піти кудись дуже далеко, іде сама ніжками й за ручку. Якщо втомиться, просить батька взяти на горгоші»* (форум про вагітність, автор з м. Первомайськ Миколаївської обл., на кордоні з Одеською).
> - МОЛДАВІЯ
>
>   - *«Іти до моря треба було через лиман по містку, я Катю носила на „горгошах“, так з цими пішими прогулянками скинула два кіло»* (форум про дітей, автор з Тирасполя).
>   - *«Мені більше подобається на горгошах їздити, ніж на руках коли носять… Чоловік іноді носив, звісно, на руках, але на горгошах не порівняти»* (жіночий форум, автор з Тирасполя).
>   - *«Стосовно слова „на гиргошах“ скажу так… Такий вислів у мене з самого дитинства, і причому не лише в мене… Все місто так каже […] І причому „на закорках“ чую вперше в житті»* (форум про дітей, автор з Тирасполя).
>   - *«Ага, готуйтеся взяти на горгоші армію обліковців та перевіряльників»* (придністровський соціальний форум).
>   - *«Взяти на плечі. У нас ще кажуть „взяти на гаргоші“»* (коментар у Живому журналі, раніше Рибниця, нині — Кишинів).
>   - *«Так, якщо в цій легкій атлетиці він мене на гаргоші візьме…»* (форум, автор з Бєльців, 38 років).
>   - *«Там ще за сюжетом Тім мав дві мили перти його на горгоші…»* (молодіжний ігровий форум, автор з Бендер).
> - ЗАХІДНА УКРАЇНА
>
>   - *«Ось туточки я йому [хлопцю] на гаргошах сиджу, тобто на шиї звісивши ноги»* (коментар у блозі, Кам'янець-Подільский; автор народилася 1981 р.).
> - Примітка: слабо фіксуються тж. варіанти **коркоски**, **киркоски**, **коркоси**, **киркоси** й **коркоші**, пор. атрибутовані приклади:
>
>   - *«Коркоски, вони ж закорки, воно ж місце на плечах, куди саджають малюка. Або дівчину на конч{ц}ерті»* (форум, Одеса).
>   - *«Приїхала свекруха в гості (з Донбасу), і я залишила чоловіка, її й сина (3,5 роки), а сама — гуляти. Повертаюся — нервова, виснажена дитина щось їм торочить і не може пояснити […] Покликали товмача в моїй особі. Ну, кажу, матусі скажи, що бажав.
>
>       — Я на коркоськи хочу!
>
>       Питаю: що незрозуміло? Виявилося, вони такого слова не знають… Специфіка регіону, однак!»* (форум про дітей, Одеса).
>   - *«Що таке ГОРГОШІ, я дізналася лише років у 25, а слово „коркоски“ взагалі вперше чую»* (там же, далі в темі інша учасниця).
>   - *«У нас це „киркоси“ були»* (там же, ще одна учасниця з Одеси).
>   - *«Настька на каркоші всаджувалася, Вітя руку батьківську брав, через плече надягнувши сумку з провізією, і вирушали вони в путь-дорогу»* (мережеве оповідання, автор з Одеси; народився 1959 р.).
>   - *«Залазь ліпше до мене на каркоші, у мене плечі є, слава Богу!»* (форум, автор з Хмельницької обл.).

«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах:

> **[горго́ші](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page563)**, *ґорґо́ші* — див. **корко́ші**.
>
> ---
>
> [**[корко́ші](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=26)**] (мн.) (у виразі [на к. кого взяти] «носити кого-небудь на спині, на плечах») Ж, [*ґорґо́ші*] (мн.) (у сполу­ченнях [*нести дитину на ґорґошах*] «нести дитину на плечах, за спиною», [*узя́ти на ґ.*]) Ме, [*ґорґе́ші*] «тс.» Гриц, [ко́ркуш] «плечі, шия, спина» Ж; — р. *(за)ко́рки* (у виразі *сесть на з.* «сі­сти на плечі, на верхню частину спини»), п. kark «задня частина шиї», ч. слц. krk «шия», вл. kyrk «горло», krk «тс.», болг. [*къ́ркач*] (у виразі [*нося на к.*] «несу на плечах і верхній частині спини»), м. *кркач* (у виразі *носи к.* «тягне (несе) на спині»), схв. *kȑke* (у виразі *nà krke nositi* «нести на плечах»), *кр̀кача* «спина, горб» (*на кр̀качама* «на плечах»), слн. kŕke (мн.) «довге волосся на голо­ві», krkoč (na krkoč «на плечах»), цсл. (схв.) кръкъ «шия»; — псл. *k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥košь (*k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥kočь), *k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥kačь (*k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥kačа), похідні від *k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥kъ «шия»; — споріднене з дінд. kṛka- (не засвідчене) «шия, горло, кадик», відбитим у kṛ́kata- «шийні хребці»; іє. *ker- «обертати, крутити, гнути» (сюди ж псл. *k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥čь, укр. *ко́рчі*); менш певні як відповідники дісл. kverk «горло, гортань», лат. gurges «стравохід», дінд. gargara- «тс.», лит. kãklas «шия» (Machek ESJC 293); виведення від *k<sup>ъ</sup>r̥čь, укр. *корчі* (Brückner 220) мало перекон­ливе; слово розглядається і як суб­стратне в індоєвропейських мовах (пор. абх. gyrgy «гортань») (Тreimer Lingua 9 (1960), 99). — Sławski ІІ 77–78; Skok ІІ 203; Bezlaj ESSJ 11 95. — Пор. **карк**, **корча́га**.